# Azure AD redirects to wrong location (localhost) after authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have code working in development that authorizes against Azure AD in a multi-tenant setup using the MSAL library (with the Microsoft Angular wrapper for MSAL).

This code all works as expected when I am running it against `localhost:5001`.

My configuration contains a `redirectUri` for `https://localhost:5001` and my application in Azure AD has its "Redirect URI" value set to the same.

However, when I move this to production, it is continuing to try to redirect me to `localhost:5001` on a successful AD authentication, even though I have changed my `redirectUri` in my configuration, as well as the Azure B2C application "Redirect URI", to now be the production site at:

> https://[mysite].azurewebsites.net

Where is it still getting `localhost:5001` from?  I searched my code/configuration and this value does not exist.  It is not currently in Azure AD for the Application.  I have stopped and restarted my App Service to no avail.

The redirection it is trying to make is to:

> https://localhost:5001/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi ...

Comment: Please mark it as answer, then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by deleting the Azure AD App Registration and creating a new one from scratch with the proper endpoints.

For some reason, it was not "holding" the change when the endpoint URLs were edited and saved.  It showed the correct endpoints in the Azure AD control panel for the App Registration, but it was still redirecting to `localhost`.

When I deleted and re-created, it properly forwarded the replies to the production site.

I am unsure at this time if this is an issue on Microsoft's side or not, but this conclusively resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete and register a new application. Simply update the replyUrlsWithType attribute on the Azure Active Directory app manifest file to point to the new domain, url or location:

```
"replyUrlsWithType": [
   {
      "url": "https://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html",
      "type": "InstalledClient"
   }
],
```

See this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps

Comment: Removing and adding back the localhost url to the manifest worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a new application solved this issue.

Comment: We are hosting the Azure AD Application in a multi-tenant configuration, where our customers authorize our application and allow users to authenticate from their ADs.  Perhaps this is the B2B and not B2C flow.  Either way I do not see anything about "User Flows" in the Azure portal for this applicatin, only a Reply URI.  Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick So you are using azure ad multi tenant, not azure ad b2c tenant, right?

Comment: Yes that would be correct, I've edited the question.  Multi-tenant AD Application.  We are using MSAL to launch with the `PopUp=true` property set.  The redirection to `localhost:5001` is actually occurring inside of the popup after successful AD authentication (the popup does not close prior to trying to go from Microsoft to localhost).  The Redirect URI is properly set in Azure AD, it does not point to localhost.

Comment: @Patrick Please check the client id in your code again, if the settings are correct, you can try to register a new one to have a try.

Comment: I ended up creating another App Registration, with the same redirect URLs I just changed the Client ID to the new one on my side and it started working.  I still am unsure why this worked, it seems something "behind the scenes" may have not been updating properly.