# Wrong Redirect to Localhost

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, electron, azure-ad-msal

I build an Angular App that communicates with the MS Graph API, to do so I used MSAL. While using "ng serve" inside Angular CLI, everything works fine.

Later I wrapped this angular App with electron to deploy it as an Desktop App. When starting electron the Login via Microsoft works fine but after Login I get redirected to a false Localhost-Address.
I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/ but my redirect URI is http://localhost:8080/#/home.

When redirected to the false Address the Error Connection Refused appears in Dev-Console/Network, and the screen stays blank in electron.

Is this a Problem with Azure AD?
I cannot delete and reregister my app in Azure AD (as seen here [Azure AD redirects to wrong location (localhost) after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757232/azure-ad-redirects-to-wrong-location-localhost-after-authentication) ), because I am in a corporate environment.

Can anybody relate to this?

Comment: Is the redirect url you set in the code the same as your redirect url in the AAD application?

Comment: yes they are both http://localhost:8080/#/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution to my problem. I changed redirects to localhost:8080/ without the Hash and everything following it. The Problem was that the Server only redirects to the part without everything after the Hash. This is because of HashLocationStrategy. So when I configure Redirect to be localhost:8080/#/ it actually redirects to localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Use `msal://redirect` as your **redirect URL in the AAD application** and as your **redirectUri variable** in the app